# React-leaflet ImageOverlay is not visible in exported PDF using jspdf

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, jspdf, react-leaflet, export-to-pdf

I'm using ***react-leaflet*** v4.2.1. I'm using it to display not a map but custom image like that

```
<MapContainer
  center={[height / 2, width / 2]}
  crs={crs}
  bounds={bounds}
  minZoom={-5}
  zoomControl={false}
  attributionControl={false}
>
  <HeatmapLayer /> // component created with leaflet.heat
  <ZoomControl position='bottomleft' />
  <ImageOverlay url={url} bounds={bounds} />
</MapContainer>
```

It's working fine. I want to export this map to pdf. I'm using ***jspdf*** library.

```
const doc = new JsPDF();
const heatmap = document.getElementById('heatmap-report')!;
const data = await html2canvas(heatmap);
const img = data.toDataURL('image/png');
const imgProperties = doc.getImageProperties(img);
const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
const pdfHeight = (imgProperties.height * pdfWidth) / imgProperties.width;
doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', 10, 150, pdfWidth - 10, pdfHeight);

doc.save('my-file.pdf');
```

The problem is that it only shows HeatmapLayer and ZoomControl and ImageOverlay is invisible.

I have also tried to use ***use-react-screenshot*** library and it also shows only HeatmapLayer and ZoomControl.

I have to export this ImageOverlay together with HeatmapLayer exactly as user sees it on the screen (so including zoom position etc) so I need to use leaflet. Do you have any ideas how can I do it?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, _specific_ question. Also, ChatGPT isn't mature enough to be useful. Please don't mention it here without at least citing _original_ sources.

Comment: @KJ not sure I understand you correctly but I tried exporting just the map (without this heatmap layer) and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. I passed base64 instead of url as url prop to ImageOverlay component.

```
  // before <ImageOverlay url={url} bounds={bounds} />
  <ImageOverlay url={base64} bounds={bounds} />
```

I think it might be related to CORS.